# R: Insert Variable into RMongo command

Tags: r, mongodb

I am currently using the `RMongo` package to provide an interface between `R` and `MongoDB`. I am querying `MongoDB` and parsing out objects by their individual ID.

An example of how this is done is given below:

```
library(RMongo)

mongo  <- mongoDbConnect("test")
output <- dbInsertDocument(mongo, "test_data", '{"foo": "bar"}')
output <- dbGetQueryForKeys(mongo, 'test_data', "{'_id': { '$oid' : '123456789' }}", '{"_id":1, "foo":1}')
output
```

Instead of typing in the ID of the object into the query as above, I wish to save the ID as some variable and insert this variable into the query. For example:

```
i <- '123456789'
output <- dbGetQueryForKeys(mongo, 'test_data', "{'_id': { '$oid' : i }}", '{"_id":1, "foo":1}')
output
```

Any help in achieving this successfully would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `paste()` or `paste0()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to insert only the variable `i`, then you can use either the `paste` or `paste0` functions:

```
i <- '123456789'
output <- dbGetQueryForKeys(mongo, 'test_data', paste("{'_id': { '$oid' : ",i,"}}", sep = "",collapse = ""), '{"_id":1, "foo":1}')
output
```

The `paste` function allows you to concatenate the variable `i` after converting it to a string. Get more info on it with `?paste`.